# how to open a different link in a new tab each 2 second without a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried different way but it doesn't work

I have 5 links:

"site1.com"
"site2.com"
"site3.com"
"site4.com"
"site5.com"

I would like that when a user comes to my site, without clicking anywhere, a link gets open each 5 sec in a new tab.

For ex: a user is reading my site, 5 secs after "site1.com" is opening in a new tab, 5 sec later "site2.com" is opening in a new tab, etc.

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Luckily, browsers block such behaviour.

Comment: thank you for your help, now I understand why my code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let link1 = document.getElementById("link1");

setTimeout(function () { 
  link1.click()
  console.log("clicked")
}, 3000);
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" id="link1">link1</a>
```